# Update data using sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I'm working on a Reactjs project. There is login/register forms after login I am able to display the user's data in an Account page.

On the Account page the user will be able to update the data he filled in when he signed up.

The form contains :

- First name
- Last name
- Email
- Phone
- Delivery address

I want to update the data using the Reactjs form.

**My code**

**Front**

```
class Account extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      deliveryAddress: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      first_name: decoded.first_name,
      last_name: decoded.last_name,
      email: decoded.email,
      phone: decoded.phone,
      deliveryAddress: decoded.deliveryAddress
    });
  }

  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { first_name, last_name, email, phone, deliveryAddress } = this.state;
    const body = {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      phone,
      deliveryAddress
    };
    const json = JSON.stringify(body);
    console.log(json);

    axios.put("http://localhost:5000/users/:id", json).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

**UserController.ts**

```
export const updateUser = (req, res) => {
  User.update(
    {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      email: req.body.email,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      deliveryAddress: req.body.deliveryAddress
    },
    {
      where: {
        id: req.body.id
      }
    }
  ).then(user => {
    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

I think my issue is in my where attribute because when I click on the Save Button I got : `Executing (default): UPDATE users SET updatedAt='2020-02-18 14:30:03' WHERE id = NULL` and nothing happens, nothing is updated.

**EDIT**

**UserController.ts**

```
export const updateUser = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  User.update(
    {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      email: req.body.email,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      deliveryAddress: req.body.deliveryAddress
    },
    {
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }
  ).then(user => {
    if (user == 1) {
      res.send({
        message: "User was updated successfully"
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        message: `Cannot update User with id=${id}. Maybe User was not found or req.body is empty!`
      });
    }
  });
};
```

When I use Postman and the request PUT on http://localhost:5000/users/10 I correctly update the user. My issue is that I can't get the id if I use my Reactjs code.

**EDIT 2**

I added the id in the state and in the componentDidMount() function as follows :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      id: decoded.id,
      first_name: decoded.first_name,
      last_name: decoded.last_name,
      email: decoded.email,
      phone: decoded.phone,
      deliveryAddress: decoded.deliveryAddress
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const {
      id,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      phone,
      deliveryAddress
    } = this.state;
    const body = {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      phone,
      deliveryAddress
    };
    const json = JSON.stringify(body);
    console.log(json);

    axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/users/${id}`, json).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

I'm now able to get the current id : `Executing (default): UPDATE users SET updatedAt='2020-02-19 08:48:57' WHERE id = '15'` but nothing happens because the first_name field is not modified like I do with Postman : `Executing (default): UPDATE users SET first_name='Quentin',updatedAt='2020-02-19 08:50:57' WHERE id = '15'`

Comment: Why are you checking that `user` is equal to 1 on success? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: This returns success if I change any field and returns the error if the id doesn't exist, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending an `id` field from the app, so you cannot do

```
where: {
  id: req.body.id
}
```

You can either make sure you save the `id` locally too and send it so your API endpoint can use it or you can do an [`upsert`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert) instead.

Another option is to find the user by email instead of ID:

```
where: {
  email: req.body.email
}
```

You would have to make sure to not allow your user to change their email from this page. Or, you can even add another field called `oldEmail` if you really need that.

EDIT: After seeing your new edit and more code, I believe I see the issue, you're not sending the ID correctly from React. You're doing:

```
axios.put("http://localhost:5000/users/:id", json).then(res => {
```

When you should really be doing the following:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/users/${this.state.id}`, json).then(res => {
```

Assuming you have the `id` field in your state and that it's an existing user.

Comment: I tried to use a findOne with email and nothing happens. Please have a look at my edit

Comment: @seiju Then it's clear that you're gonna need to share some more server code. It looks like your endpoint is not receiving the data correctly. Could it be that you didn't setup bodyParser?

Comment: I'm using bodyParser, I added Server.ts code in my edit

Comment: All of my other requests work, I think the problem is from my updateUser function

Comment: Please, share the code of the endpoint that's calling `updateUser`.

Comment: Ok I will test this tomorrow, thanks for answer me. I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: I've tested as you can see in my Edit 2 but I can't change any field yet

Comment: Did you try console logging the value of your `req.body`? `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`. What are you getting? @seiju

Comment: You mean in the backend ? Yes I get the values of the fields correctly.

Comment: Interesting thing : When I update with Reactjs form : `{"{\"first_name\":\"Test1\",\"last_name\":\"Test2\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"phone\":\"0606060606\",\"deliveryAddress\":\"Test address\"}":""}` and when I update with Postman : `{"first_name":"Test1","last_name":"Test2","email":"test@test.com","phone":"0606060606","deliveryAddress":"Test address"}`

Comment: I believe it's because you're stringifying your body object. Just send `body` instead of sending `json`. @seiju

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept my answer with, maybe, an upvote.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to update React to display the new data after I updated it ? For now I have to logout and then login to refresh data from database

Comment: Something like this should work: `axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/users/${id}`, body).then(res => {
  this.setState(body)
});` You just update the state once it's successfully updated server-side.

Comment: You're gonna have to ask a new question on here.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thanks for you help